# reference types - new keyword to create its value

Tags: c#, delegates, value-type, reference-type

I believe some literature is not accurate (mayebe even contains mistakes) or its my fault?
Book I currently read says (translation):

> To create a value of reference type,
>   new keyword has to be used.

I do not think so - what about delegates? Am I correct or do I understand that text badly?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not *always* going to be true, no. Some examples:

- String concatenation
- Delegate conversions
- Boxing conversions

Other examples where `new` won't appear in your *source* code would include user-defined operators and conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Delegates are also implicitly created with the new keyword. Behind the scenes, the compiler is generating the necessary code for you. So

```
MyEvent += SomeMethod;
```

becomes

```
MyEvent += new EventHandler(someInstance, SomeMethod);
```

but it's true, not every time a reference type is created, the `new` operator is needed. like boxing.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are reference to a function, and as you probably know, you don't use the "new" keyword when declaring a function.

but you do use it when declaring an object, like:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
```